# VueJS + VUEX: Async + await (how to compose actions)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am asking myself how to compose `actions` with the keywords `async` and `await`.

What's the difference between them? And what do they accomplish?

All I know about actions is that they can "invoke" mutations, like this:

```
CREATE_USER({ commit }) {
  commit('createUser')
}
```

So my question is:

How do you compose actions in VueJS the common way?

Comment: I'd read this: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html And then I'd read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I'd rather want a real explanation ...

Comment: Your question is too broad, so I think you'll have trouble getting a clear answer. Vuex actions and async functions are well documented, so you should read up on them first. Then if there is any *specific* issue you're having when using them, you could post a question related to your issue.

Comment: okay. then I will have to wait a little till I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this page https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html.

You could compose your actions normally like the one you wrote, or with Promise or with the new ES features async await. Async and await are similar to Promise. They make it easier to work with asynchronously code in JavaScript.